# How to hide a button that is affixed when it 'floats' over a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button `back-to-top` that is affixed to the left side of the screen - it uses `scrollTop` to slide-scroll to the top of the page when it's clicked. When the page the loads, the button is visible and does not cover anything that is readable etc.

When a user scrolls down the page, the button goes over certain DIVs that have text content. When the button goes into such a DIV I want it to hide using `.hide()`. Can't get it to work, here's what I have:

```
    var p = $('a.back-to-top');
    var position = p.position();

    if(position == $('#about-me')){
        $('a.back-to-top').hide();
    }
```

Is `if(position == $('#about-me'))` the correct way to check if the button's position is in the `#about-me` DIV? Or, should I create a variable similar to `position` for the DIV?

EDIT: A messy but simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygQbS/)

Comment: Could you post a simple demo showing a relevant/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) sample of the code you've got so far, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do this check inside of a callback .. probably `$(window).scroll` so that it is checked each time the window scrolls; otherwise, it is only checked when the page loads.

I don't think you want to use `position` either as that is position relative to parent.  Instead, you probably want `.offset`.  This returns an object with `top` and `left` members.  An `==` comparison does not make sense, especially to a jQuery object.  You want to use:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
   var offset = $("a.back-to-top").offset().top;

   var within = $("#about-me").offset().top;

   if (offset >= within && offset <= within + $("#about-me").height()) {
      $("a.back-to-top").hide();
   }
   else {
      $("a.back-to-top").show();
   }
});​
```

The offset of `.back-to-top` changes with scrolling if it has a fixed position, but the offset of the static block does not change, so you can do this comparison.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/QnhgF/

Comment: I didn't realise that position returned an abject, I thought it would have given me something similar to using screen.width. I'm new enough to jQuery! Appreciate the explanation and solution.

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/position/ - position() method returns a position object which has .left and .top properties. So basically, you can't compare position to some object returned by a selector. Instead, you should compare the "top" property values of both elements.
For example you have:

```
var p = $('a.back-to-top');
var position = p.position();
```

Also get this:

```
var aboutMePosition = $('#about-me').position();
```

And then you can compare:

aboutMePosition.top and position.top whichever way you need.

Comment: This should only be accurate if the 2 DOM elements are direct siblings contained in the same DOM container.

Comment: And if not - you can use offset() instead of position() :)